# External resources are not loading when installing my PWA (Service worker issues?)

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I made this PWA in [dorothyophals.com](https://dorothyophals.com) and is working like a charm! But when I install it on my iPhone or iPad, there is video loading from uploads.dorothyophals.com and it doesn't work. it works from the browser though if you want to test it.

Another issue I can see is that the player shows the time of the song playing at the top of the page. But when I play the song on the installed pwa it only show NAN:NAN

I'm I missing something? Can somebody help me with this service worker or what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Playback of audio/video content on the web normally involves a `Range:` request and a partial response. This can be [problematic](https://philna.sh/blog/2018/10/23/service-workers-beware-safaris-range-request/) from within a service worker unless you're prepared to handle it.

Assuming that you don't plan on caching your media files and you want the response to come directly from the network, I'd recommend changing your service worker's `fetch` handler so that it doesn't call `respondWith()` when the associated request has a `Range:` header.

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", function(event) {
  if (event.request.headers.has('Range')) {
    // Returning, without calling event.respondWith(),
    // will cause the browser to handle the request as
    // if there were no service worker involvement.
    return;
  }

  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
      if (response) {
        return response;
      }
      return fetch(event.request);
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, I do want to cache at least the songs, not necessarily the video, but I would like the song samples to be available to hear even offline. I should add though that when I updated the iOS on my phone and my wife’s phone it worked, so I’m assuming Apple is adding more support for PWA ever update.

Comment: https://philna.sh/blog/2018/10/23/service-workers-beware-safaris-range-request/ has some details on handling cached media playback. There's also https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#cached-av if you want to use Workbox.